# Adding a blog to wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, static, blogs

I have designed a website in Wordpress using static pages and I would also like to add blog feature to it.

On my static homepage, I would like to include a small blogroll, linked to full blog-page. (just like if my home page was set to blog instead of home page).

In other words, I want to utilize together both page and blog features, but setting static page as main page makes it impossible to view all the posts written on the websites. 
If i set blog page as homepage, then i loose my static homepage, but i get page with all the posts written.

How can I actually create a link from static homepage to a page with all blog-posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **[Reading Settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen)** page of the admin area (Settings > Reading; the same place you select your static front page) there is a selector called **Posts page**. Select the page that you would like the blog posts displayed on (this will override any content you actually have on that page).

You can also create a file named [`home.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) in your template's folder with your [post display code](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and when you navigate to `www.example.com/home.php` it will display.